# Does it make sense that these high numbers are midi tempo?

Tags: actionscript-3, midi, tempo

I am using midi library for as3 and receive these values as tempo (to the left the timeline and to the right the tempo)

1712 11424264

3632 11424264

3670 2325000

3708 1417992

Assuming that at time=0 the tempo=500000. The first valus is 200 times higher, how come it is too high? Perhaps I am reading it wrong? When I try to calculate the real time of notes using that tempo I get high values, which are probably incorrect.

Comment: Are you reading a MIDI file, or off the wire?  If file, can you post the entire header chunk, in hex?  If off the wire, can you post the messages in question?

Comment: the problem was that I didn't read the hex file correctly. now it is okay and the timing sync great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tempo isn't a value in beats per minute (like 120 BPM), which I have a feeling you are expecting to get. [MIDI tempo](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midifile/tempo.htm) is given in microseconds per quarter note.

As for the values being 200 times higher, yes, that probably is a bit suspicious. Either you are asking the wrong question (ie, you are not receiving actual MIDI tempo events, but something else which is not a tempo change event), or the MIDI files are really crazy. The best way to confirm that is to simply load them in a sequencer and see the events there.

Comment: thanks for your help. I should have written that these values (11424264 etc...) are microseconds per quarter note, that I already know. I will recheck things. perhaps I am reading the hex wrong (though it seems okay). Do you have a name of a midi sequencer I can get? if there is a free-simple one just for the check then it could be better...

Comment: Perhaps I read the hex file wrong - here is the value I wrote: 0xAE5208 = 11 424 264, but perhaps I should read it in opposite direction and get: 0x0852AE = 545 454 ?

Comment: I was right! all I needed to do is read the hex file in the opposite direction. the values are correct - the timing sync perfectly.

Comment: Glad that worked for you! Be sure to mark the answer as correct if you think that it is right, that way other people stumbling across this question from google can benefit from your knowledge. ;)